# Finding the limit of a function with 2 variables

Tags: calculus, limits

Please help to solve the limit.

$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\dfrac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}$$

I tried to solve it but...

$$x:=0 \Rightarrow \dfrac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2} = y$$
$$y:=0 \Rightarrow \dfrac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2} = x$$

Comment: What's your problem? Both $x$ and $y$ are well-defined at $(0,0)$, and give rise to the same limit.

Answer (score 2):

$$x:=r\cos\theta$$
$$y:=r\sin\theta$$

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}=\lim_{r\to0}\frac{r^3\cos^3\theta+r^3\sin^3\theta}{r^2}=\lim_{r\to0}r(\cos^3\theta+\sin^3\theta)=0$$

Comment: That's only considering the limit along straight lines.

Comment: $r$ and $\theta$ are functions that depend on $x$ and $y$ . For sure $|\cos\theta+\sin\theta|\lt 2$,  So the argument works for all paths.

Answer (score 2):

Hints: (i) If $x^2+y^2$ is involved, switching to polar can be useful. Let $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$.

(ii) If one does not wish to use the approach (i), note that
$$|x^3+y^3|=|x+y|(x^2-xy+y^2)\le |x+y|(2x^2+2y^2).$$

(iii) Alternately, let $\epsilon \gt 0$. If $(x,y)$ is close enough to $(0,0)$, then $|x|\lt \epsilon$ and $|y|\lt \epsilon$. Thus $|x^3|\lt \epsilon x^2$ and $|y^3|\lt \epsilon y^2$, and therefore 
$$\frac{|x^3+y^3|}{x^2+y^2}\le \frac{|x^3|+|y^3|}{x^2+y^2}\lt \frac{\epsilon x^2+\epsilon y^2}{x^2+y^2}.$$